# Truth-value multisets with only one type of element

Tags: reference-request, truth

Suppose we had a multiset of truth-values [T, T], and that was it. Letting those be indexed as T1 and T2, suppose a twofold fragmenting of a related set of propositions (maybe not a set of all-propositions-whatsoever) and say that propositions from fragment *A* are true only when they map to T1 and *B*'s elements go with T2. Then, however, sometimes elements of *B* map to T1, say: and that is how falsity arises, here (mismatches of T-maps).

**Is that enough to have a theory of falsehood in a truth-value multiset, or would attempts to translate/encode [T, T] as {T, F} not work out like that at all?**

---

**Precedent:**

[Čulina[21]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.12157.pdf) includes the following:

[image]

---

I don't know how well the following can be applied, here, or to the request for an example of how to separate propositions into two sets for the purposes of attempting the rest of the idea, [but](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/16406/1/Costa-Leite%20%28SAJL%29.pdf):

[image]

This occurs in a discussion of a one-dimensional example of an *n*-dimensional type of "oppositional geometries." In writings about such graph-like things that I am previously familiar with, the main author (Alessio Moretti) focuses on a need to use bi-simplexes to "geometrically complete" the graphs (I think he says that he doesn't want the geometries to be taken for just graphs with logical flavoring, so maybe we should take them as generalized over a variable graph-theoretic type that ranges over the conceptual differences between graphs, multigraphs, and hypergraphs; but otherwise I'm not sure why the geometries are sufficiently distinct from samples of those structures). I think some of the simplexes that Moretti uses are at a flipped angle compared to the ones they're paired with in whole bi-simplexes, but otherwise, having them side-by-side might be like having [A, A].

Comment: Give an example.

Comment: @Daron offhand (I thought of truth-value multisets just yesterday, so I haven't had time to think through the possible "experiments in logic" very much) let's say ethics propositions really are non-factual/non-realist in some robust manner, except here it turns out that they're factual/realist for a different T-multielement than propositions about non-ethical topics are. (I don't think the bare concept of facts is strong enough to support the "fact/value" or "is/ought" distinction, but stronger abstract definitions of facts might support those.)

Comment: Otherwise, the idea seems like it could be used in a semantics for substructural logics with premise repetition. There's a reliable contributor here who I think is invested in questions of substructural logic, I'm thinking that he'll be familiar with information pertinent to my question. So maybe such an idea has already been used like so, and that's what I'll find out.

Comment: I mean an example of a "twofold fragmenting of a related set of propositions".

Comment: @Daron well "ethical propositions vs. non-ethical propositions" does that trick too, doesn't it? IIRC, Russell thought that the set of propositional functions outweighed the set of objects (or something along those lines) and we might go on to think that there are "too many" propositions, that "all of them" form a proper class rather than a proper set, but then I suppose we could work with a proper class of ordered pairs of propositions nevertheless, maybe.

Comment: I don't think you are using the multiset of truth values in the way Čulina is. Čulina is claiming that identity, and quantifiers that depend on identity for their definition such as E!, do not qualify as logical symbols under his definition because one cannot determine the truth value of (a=b) or (E!x)Fx just from a knowledge of the language alone. E.g. We can map a set of sentences to a multiset of their truth values, but we cannot determine the multiplicity of T within that multiset without knowledge of the world that gave us those truth valuations...

Comment: Čulina is not trying to formulate a theory of falsehood; he is assuming that T and F are a primitive bivalent pairing. (Incidentally, I don't think his account really works, but that is another issue.)

Comment: @Bumble What is a "primitive bivalent pairing"?

Comment: @Daron I mean that Čulina is simply taking for granted that sentences are bivalent and that true and false are the only values, i.e. that he is working within the realm of classical logic. On the basis of this assumption, we do not need a theory of falsehood, because if a sentence is not true it is false and if it is not false it is true and that's all there is to it. If I understand Kristian Berry he is aiming to construct a theory of what it is for a sentence to be false that goes beyond this.

Comment: @Bumble yeah, I really wish I could have followed the point he was making, on its own terms. In terms of my OP question here, I just wonder if we can use his snippet as justification for asking about truth-value multisets in general, *then* passing to the question of how to use such creatures. I did think of another grounding, though: Alessio Moretti obsesses over his "hyperflowers" being bi-simplexes, so maybe a truth-value bi-simplex consisting of two nodes could be taken as a multigraph of [T, T] such that the -opposition theory Moretti uses is where F-likeness comes in.

Answer (score 1):

In logic we have some propositions, and we are interested in some special functions from the set of propositions to the set of truth values {*T*, *F*}. For example we want the functions to commute with the AND and OR operations. You are proposing replacing the truth values with a multiset, that contains two copies of *T* and considering functions that can map propositions to one of the two copies. That's not a multiset. That's just a set with a bad choice of notation.

A multiset over the universe Ω for example is defined as a function Ω → ℕ. In your case the universe contains the symbol *T* and maybe some other stuff, and your truth multiset is the function *F* with *F*(*T*) = 2 and *F*(*x*) = 0 for *x* ≠ *T*. Looking at it like this, it is not at all clear what a map from a set of propositions into this multiset is supposed to mean.

Comment: The function on [T, T] is not a multiset "just like that" but only [T, T] itself is (let T = 1 and go to [1, 1], for example). And on one level, I'm wondering if we could replace the usual notion of falsity as a qualitatively distinct element of {T, F}. On a metalinguistic level, we'd like to show how the mismatch parameter for mappings to [T1, T2] lines up with our intuitive notion of falsity, although I don't know if that's a stable proposal (hence my question); or, perhaps worse, there'd be a vicious circle where the mismatch-talk depends on a prior sense of falsity-talk.

Comment: As far as AND and OR go (or IF, for that matter), I've no clue yet how we'd work them out in this case and for now I don't want to presuppose that I'm trying to maintain the relevant commutativity (my most recent analysis of many-valued logic suggested over 7 truth values, if not arbitrarily many all-things-considered, and I got a decent truth-table system for AND/OR/IF out of that, but not something I've "proven" entirely useful/adequate).

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand the definition of a multiset.

Comment: Project Euclid has "Multiset Theory" which says: "A multiset is a collection of elements in which elements are allowed to repeat." I don't see that there's much, if any, of an absolute definition beyond that. Now, I upvoted your answer since I've seen that you've made contributions to the MathSE/OF and so I assume you are familiar with these topics, but you still need to cite your sources here or else I can't continue with that assumption.

Comment: The rigorous definition is in the second paragraph of my answer. The function F(x) denotes what you would intuitively understand as the number of repetitions of each element x.

Comment: I'm still going to need a source accompanied by a justification for preferring the given definition over the generic definition from the PE article.

Comment: The same article: "One  could  also  define  a multiset  which  contains the element x  with  multiplicity  n to  be a function  which contains  the  ordered  pair  (x,n).  "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147235/discussion-between-kristian-berry-and-daron).